DownloadContentAsync returning weird value for existing file
I have stored some XSLT files in azure blob storage and use
BlobClient.DownloadContentAsync()

to download content in .net function app and process. For other xslt files , everything is fine but for 1. above method is just returning me something like below.
��
Yes that's it, the file is valid xslt file. and I have verified that I am pointing to correct storage account by trying to delete the file.When I did this, the code did throw an error of non existant file. Not exactly sure, what could be the reason of above behaviour.

Please edit your question and include full code.

Maybe it's the matter of encoding?

it was indeed due to encoding on the file.


For other xslt files , everything is fine but for 1. above method is just returning me something like below.
��

The error you experiencing may be related to how the content is being downloaded and interpreted, possibly due to encoding or some corruption in the file while downloading it and also check the specific file how it stored in the storage account with correct format.
Here is the sample code that downloads the xslt file with proper result.
Code:
using System;
using System.Text;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

class Program
{
    static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = "xxxx";
        string containerName = "venkat";
        string blobName = "sample.xslt"; 
  
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

        try
        {
            BlobDownloadResult download = await blobClient.DownloadContentAsync();
            var content = download.Content;
            string xsltContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(content.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("XSLT Content: ");
            Console.WriteLine(xsltContent);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

The above downloads the content of a blob from an Azure Storage account and the downloaded content is assumed to be UTF-8 encoded, and it is converted to a string using the Encoding.UTF8.GetString method.
Output:
XSLT Content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- Root element of the XSLT -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Sample XSLT Transformation</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h2>Transformed XML Data</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- Match each 'person' element in the XML -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="people/person">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="age" /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="city" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


